# How can I automatically save my UITextField data? Easy answer would be nice

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, save, automatic-ref-counting

I have built an app which is already downloadable in the App Store, but the most important thing doesn't happen. I got my app with 208 UITextFields and they do not automatically save. It is important to happen, because otherwise the app is useless. I have read some answers on forums, but I did not have the particular tabs or I couldn't understand the answer. I am only a 16 year old developer from Holland and do not understand all hard English program language. So please answer this question soon and please a simple (might be long) answer. I can also send you my application if you want, then you can change things for  yourself.

Comment: 208 text fields sounds like fun. How did your "useless" app get on the app store? For a good answer you will need to give some more information. Do you have any persistence mechanism in place at the moment (core data, property lists etc). What are you currently doing with the data from these text fields? You say they don't automatically save, but do they manually save?

Comment: oke: The users of my app need to fill in textfields and later they can go back to the app and see the things they filled in earlier. BUT: the text they fill in, in the textfields disappears when they totally close the app. I saw some people programming a save and load button in their app, but that's not what I want. I want that the text automatically saves when the close the app. Does anyone have a clear answer?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following method.,

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(savetextfield:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)savetextfield:(NSTimer*)timer
{
   NSString *mystriing=textField.text;
}
```

This above method is for coping the only one textField value. By using Timer object we can call a method Repeatedly.

Comment: This is a ridiculous "solution". How does assigning the content of a field to a local variable persist anything? And why on earth would you do it with a timer?

Comment: By using timer, we can easily call a method repeatedly. If you want to  restrict that refer Textfield delegate methods like editingdidend().

Comment: The delegate methods would be a much better place to implement any persistence logic.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening up here. What and where do you type this in and what happens? Like I said. I am only 16 and from the Netherlands. English program language is not understandable for me.